# Using FOR XML to Concatenate multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, for-xml-path

My Data is structured like this:

[image]

and I'm trying to use STUFF/FOR XML PATH to concatenate fields.

If I use the examples that I find online I can get the following result:

[image]

But I wondered if the following is possible:

[image]

I am currently achieving this by calling FOR XML PATH twice, first to concatenate Header3:

[image]

and then again to get the desired result.

Is there a way to do it without calling XML PATH twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Header1 INT,
  Header2 VARCHAR(45),
  Header3 VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(123, 'A', 'aaa'),
(123, 'B', 'bbb'),
(123, 'C', 'ccc'),
(123, 'C', 'ddd'),
(456, 'E', 'eee');

WITH H3 AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT Header1, Header2,
         STUFF(
           (
             SELECT ',' + Header3
             FROM T
             WHERE Header2 = H2.Header2
             FOR XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 1, ''
         ) Res
FROM T H2
)

SELECT DISTINCT
       Header1,
       STUFF(
         (SELECT ' '+ Header2 + ':' + Res + '|'
          FROM H3
          WHERE Header1 = TT.Header1
          FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, ''
       ) Desired
FROM H3 TT;
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------+--------------------------+
| Header1 |         Desired          |
+---------+--------------------------+
|     123 | A:aaa| B:bbb| C:ccc,ddd| |
|     456 | E:eee|                   |
+---------+--------------------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=511cd56818d6700f8533c8752962fd52)**

Comment: I am.  This is a lot cleaner and clearer than my current query so thank you.  But I was hoping to see if it could be done without calling FOR XML twice.

Comment: @DCulley, This structure is a doubled `1:n` relation actually (that clearly points to the fact, that this screams for a different table design). However, You need some kind of join or (correlated) sub-query to gather all the related `Header2` data and one more step to bind the related `Header3` data to their correspoding `Header2`. This might be solved better in your presentation layer...